# Simpson's method for numerically computing the integration of a function

Tags: c#, numerical-methods

I have implemented the [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) for numerical integration.

[**Check this video for the implemented function.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns3k-Lz7qWU)

```
namespace Simpsons_method_of_integration
{
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns3k-Lz7qWU
    using System;

    public class Simpson
    {
        private double Function(double x)
        {
            return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(x, 5)); //Define the function f(x)
        }

        public double Compute(double a, double b, int n)
        {
            double[] x = new double[n + 1];

            double delta_x = (b - a) / n;

            x[0] = a;

            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)//calculate the values of x1, x2, ...xn
            {
                x[j] = a + delta_x * j;
            }

            double sum = Function(x[0]);

            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    sum += 4 * Function(x[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += 2 * Function(x[j]);
                }
            }

            sum += Function(x[n]);

            double integration = sum * delta_x / 3;

            return integration;
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Simpson simpson = new Simpson();
            double a = 0d;//lower limit a
            double b = 3d;//upper limit b
            int n = 6;//Enter step-length n

            if (n % 2 == 0)//n must be even
            {
                Console.WriteLine(simpson.Compute(a, b, n));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("n should be an even number");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
1.07491527775614
```

---

How can I make this source code more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> ```
>     if (j % 2 != 0)
>     {
>       sum += 4 * Function(x[j]);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       sum += 2 * Function(x[j]);
>     }
> ```

can be expressed as:

```
    sum += (2 << (j % 2)) * Function(x);
```

---

In order to make your algorithm more useful, you should inject the `Function` as a delegate parameter to the method, and also make it `static`:

```
public static double Compute(Func<double, double> fx, double a, double b, int n)
{
  double h = (b - a) / n;

  double sum = fx(a) + fx(b);
  double x = a;
  for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
  {
    x += h;
    sum += (2 << (j % 2)) * fx(x);
  }

  return sum * h / 3;
}
```

Used as:

```
Simpson.Compute(x => 1 / (1 + Math.Pow(x, 5)), a, b, n);
```

Answer (score 5):

- There is no reason to allocate the `double[] x` array. It is better to compute the argument as you go: initialize `double x = a;` and increment it `x += delta_x;` in the loop body.
- `if` in the loop is usually a performance killer. Consider incrementing `j` by 2:

  ```
      for (int j = 1; j < n; j += 2)
      {
          sum += 2 * Function(x);
          x += delta_x;
          sum += 4 * Function(x);
          x += delta_x;
      }
  ```

  Now depending on the parity of `n` the very last addition could be wrong, and you need to compensate for it.
- `Function` shall not be a `Simpson`'s method. The `Simpson` shall not care what it integrates. Change the signature of `Compute` to accept the callable.
- The choice of \$\dfrac{1}{1 + x^5}\$ for an integrand looks strange. It is hard to verify that the result is correct. I recommend to test against some more friendly integrands first.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `double[]`.

Example implementation that only loops once and discards the array:

```
public static double ComputeV2(double a, double b, int n)
{
    double deltaX = DeltaX(a, b, n);

    // start with a sum of x_0 and x_n:
    double sum = Function(a) + Function(a + deltaX * n);

    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        sum += Function(a + deltaX * j) * (j % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 4);
    }

    return Integrate(sum, deltaX);
}
```

And if you're into LINQ, something like this also works:

```
public static double ComputeLinq(double a, double b, int n)
{
    double deltaX = DeltaX(a, b, n);

    double sum =
        Enumerable
        .Range(1, n - 1)
        .Select(j => Function(a + deltaX * j) * (j % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 4))
        .Aggregate(
            seed: Function(a) + Function(a + deltaX * n),
            func: (acc, v) => acc + v);

    return Integrate(sum, deltaX);
}
```

As for performance, here are some micro benchmarks:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.720 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)
Intel Core i7-8650U CPU 1.90GHz (Kaby Lake R), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.2.301
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.2.6 (CoreCLR 4.6.27817.03, CoreFX 4.6.27818.02), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.2.6 (CoreCLR 4.6.27817.03, CoreFX 4.6.27818.02), X64 RyuJIT

|      Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|   SimpsonV1 | 286.6 ns |  5.53 ns | 11.30 ns | 285.9 ns |
|   SimpsonV2 | 270.1 ns |  5.52 ns | 14.04 ns | 267.0 ns |
| SimpsonLinq | 510.8 ns | 11.67 ns | 34.23 ns | 500.1 ns |
```

As you can see, using LINQ is clearly slower, but is often more readable (not really in this case, in my opinion).

"My" version is a bit faster than yours, but it's very negligible. The biggest gain is readability and succinctness, but I bet some will find it to be "too" short for its own good.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to performance or efficiency, I don't see anything that begs for attention.

I would suggest `Simpson` class and its methods be `static`.  You really are not saving any properties or state between invocations, so `static` makes more sense.

The method named `Function` is a horrible name.  Far too generic.

I'm not even keen on the method name `Compute`, though it is an action verb.  I'd be partial to `Integrate` which is also an action verb but more descriptive.  The parameter names are decent.  Since Simpson's Rule uses the non-descript `a` and `b`, it's okay that your method does as well.  Perhaps `n` could be given a more descriptive name.

Your use of braces and indentation looks good.  Also good that `Function` is `private` and `Compute` is `public`.  However, you do not provide any validation checks on `public` methods.  What if someone entered `-999` as the value for `n`?